# Cython function performs differently based on where it is called from

Tags: performance, cython

I'm trying to process a binary file with a know format. This format involves chunks of a header, followed by variable length data. There are three levels to this structures, groups (can also appear as subgroups in a group's data), records and fields (that are not represented in the code yet).

My issue is that the read method of the Record type below takes (on profiling) 2 seconds on average to run 870,000 times while if I call it from a separate function:

```
cdef Record header
cdef unsigned char header_type[4]
cdef FILE *fileobject = fopen('filename', 'rb')
for _ in range(900000):
    fread(&header_type, 4, 1, fileobject)
    header = Record()
    header.read(fileobject)
    fseek(fileobject, 0, SEEK_SET)
```

takes about 250ms to run.

The code I'm running is:

```
# cython: profile=True

import collections
from libc.stdio cimport *


cdef class Record:
    cdef unsigned long flags, id, revision
    cdef unsigned short version, unknown

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.flags = 0
        self.id = 0
        self.revision = 0
        self.version = 0
        self.unknown = 0

    cdef void read(self, FILE* fileobject):
        cdef unsigned long data_size = 0

        # reading it all in a chunk gave the same speed
        # also tried skipping over the header, same speed

        fread(&data_size, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.flags, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.id, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.revision, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.version, 1, 2, fileobject)
        fread(&self.unknown, 1, 2, fileobject)

        # here would be a similar loop as the one in the GRUP 
        # read method to parse the fields.
        fseek(fileobject, data_size, SEEK_CUR)


cdef class GRUP:
    cdef signed long group_type
    cdef unsigned short stamp, unknown1, version, unknown2
    cdef char label[4]
    cdef list data

    def __init__(self):
        self.label = [b'0', b'0', b'0', b'0']
        self.group_type = 0
        self.stamp = 0
        self.unknown1 = 0
        self.version = 0
        self.unknown2 = 0
        self.data = []

    cdef read(self, FILE* fileobject):
        cdef long int group_size = 0
        cdef long int end_data_position = 0
        cdef char record_type[4]
        cdef GRUP group
        cdef Record record

        # reading it all in a chunk gave the same speed
        # also tried skipping over the header, same speed

        fread(&group_size, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.label, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.group_type, 1, 4, fileobject)
        fread(&self.stamp, 1, 2, fileobject)
        fread(&self.unknown1, 1, 2, fileobject)
        fread(&self.version, 1, 2, fileobject)
        fread(&self.unknown2, 1, 2, fileobject)

        end_data_position = ftell(fileobject) + group_size - 24
        while ftell(fileobject) < end_data_position:
            fread(&record_type, 1, 4, fileobject)
            if record_type[:4] == b'GRUP':
                group = GRUP()
                group.read(fileobject)
                self.data.append(group)
            else:
                record = Record()
                record.read(fileobject)
                self.data.append(record)


cdef class ESP(object):
    cdef object top_groups
    cdef Record header

    def __init__(self):
        self.header = None
        self.top_groups = collections.OrderedDict()


cpdef read(str source):
    cdef unsigned char header_type[4]
    cdef unsigned char group_type[4]
    cdef size_t bytes_read

    result = ESP()

    cdef FILE *fileobject = fopen(source.encode('UTF-8'), 'rb')
    if fileobject == NULL:
        raise TypeError("source argument is not a valid filename.")

    fread(&header_type, 1, 4, fileobject)
    result.header = Record()
    result.header.read(fileobject)

    while True:
        bytes_read = fread(&group_type, 1, sizeof(group_type), fileobject)
        if bytes_read < 4:
            break
        group = GRUP()
        group.read(fileobject)
        result.top_groups[group.label.decode()] = group

    fclose(fileobject)

    return result
```

The [profiling data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlUea.png). The target time would be under a second (this would include parsing the fields). What am I doing wrong that makes it run so slow or what can I do further?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Could you explain the line "My issue is that the read method of the Record type below takes (on profiling) 2 seconds on average to run 870,000 times while if I call it from a separate function:" Is the difference between `result.header.read` vs `header.read`?

Comment: I'm terrible at explaining myself sorry. The difference is that when Record.read is being called from GRUP.read (in the loop) it takes 2 seconds (there are 870,000 records in that file as you can see from the profile) but if I call it from a separate function (like the sample I posted above the code) it only takes 250ms to run 900,000 times. Why this difference?

Comment: Understand now! I'm not sure - the three differences I can see are: 1) You have a string comparison in `GRUP.read` (I doubt it's that). 2) You have an array append in `GRUP.read` (it _might_ be that). 3) Your separate test function is constantly looping back to the start of the file so can probably store all of it in memory and never have to read from the disk (I think this is most likely)

Comment: (I'm deleted my commends about globals by the way; they aren't going to help anyone...)

Comment: But does the profile include all of that in the read total time? Commented out the append, [pretty much the same.](http://i.imgur.com/lqdTx7r.png) So the "true" speed is the 2 seconds rather than the 250ms? Can't C read a file faster than that? (the file is 230MB) Or is cython slower than C here and I should just learn C and rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: I think (I'm trying to write a simple test to show this...) that your limited by the disk, and the fseek back to 0 is avoiding having to read the disk. I suspect writing it in C will be very very similar. If I can get the test to work I'll post it as an answer

Comment: I honestly thought io would be faster o.0 3 seconds for a 230MB file seems a lot. Would reading the entire file in the beginning and then parsing the array be faster? And if so, could you point me to an example of parsing from an array? (I've looked but couldn't find anything)

Comment: I got the opposite result I was expecting (fseek makes it slower) so I'm afraid I don't know... sorry!

Comment: Where does fseek make it slower? And thanks!

Comment: So I was thinking the line in your separate function `fseek(fileobject, 0, SEEK_SET)` might speed it up because it's only reading a tiny bit of the file over and over again. But at least on my computer it slows it down, so that theory about the difference doesn't help you...

Comment: I would expect program that calls `fread` many times with small `size` and `nmemb` arguments to be slow regardless of the programming language used. It would be better to read larger chunks of data with `fread`.